# Replicating console functionality with a ListView

Tags: java, javafx

I apologize for not being able to think of a more descriptive title.

I have managed to redirect the system.out to a new ListView via my own OutputStream class `Console`:

```
public class Console extends OutputStream {

private ListView<String> output;

public Console(ListView<String> output)  {
    this.output = output;
}

private void addText(String str) {
    Platform.runLater( () -> output.getItems().add(str) );
}

@Override
public void write(int b) throws IOException {
    addText(String.valueOf((char) b));      
}

@Override
public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
    addText(new String(b, off, len));
}

@Override
public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
    write(b, 0, b.length);
}

}
```

Here, I create the console in my controller class. `output` is the name of the
 ListView in my FXML:

```
private void buildConsole() {
    Console console = new Console(output);
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(console, true);
    System.setOut(ps);
    System.setErr(ps);
}
```

Here is where I am testing the output with an event handler that prints the tile coordinates over which my mouse is hovering:

```
tile.setOnMouseEntered(e -> {
   tile.setFill(hoverColor);
   showConnections(tile);
   gridController.getCoordinateLabel().setText(tile.getVertex().toString());
        System.out.print("Tile " + tile.getVertex().toString() + " selected.");
    });
```

Notice that I am using `System.out.print()` and not `println()`. This is the output:

[image: system.out.print]

If I were to use `println()`:

[image: system.out.println]

My ideal behavior is:
`system.out.print()` - text to be added to the same line.
`system.out.println()` - text added to the next cell.

Comment: why would end user make the call about which of the 2 methods to use?

Comment: I don't think what you describe is very consistent.  It does not make sense for your output stream to create a new cell for every single invocation of a `write()` method.  What about splitting cells at newlines, instead?

Comment: I don't think I've correctly described the functionality I am looking for - let me make an edit. If I use `system.out.print()`, I would like the text to be added to the same line. If I use `system.out.println()`, I would like the text added to the next cell.

Comment: @DylanRussell, that is indeed different, but it *still* doesn't make sense.  The user of `PrintStream.println()` generally expects that whatever he prints starts out on the current line (i.e. cell), but that whatever is printed *next* will go to a new line (cell).  But you also need to consider what the correct interpretation should be of a literal newline being written.

Comment: I understand. I am simply looking for the exact same functionality you would expect in your IDE console. I am using a ListView because I understand that to be significantly more efficient than a text area.

Comment: Maybe another Stream writter can do as you wish, or you can implement one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are looking for behavior that corresponds to a system or IDE console, that corresponds, in part, to splitting the output into logical units (i.e. "lines") at newline characters.  That would happen automatically if you just collected whatever is written and appended it to a text area, so I would encourage you to try that and see.  Even if it turns out to be less efficient, it may still be plenty efficient for your purposes.

If you want to proceed with the ListView, however, then your `Console` class needs to internally *buffer* the data written to it, scan for newlines, and break up the output into cells at newlines.  It create a new cell *only* when it sees a newline, and in that case include all the buffered text up to, but not including that newline.

---

**Update**:

A `ByteArrayOutputStream` would make a fine buffer.  Something like this, for example:

```
public class Console extends OutputStream {

    private ListView<String> output;

    private ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    public Console(ListView<String> output)  {
        this.output = output;
    }

    private void addText() throws IOException {
        String text = buffer.toString("UTF-8");
        buffer.reset();
        Platform.runLater( () -> output.getItems().add(text) );
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        if (b == '\n') {
            addText();
        } else {
            buffer.write(b);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        int bound = off + len;
        for (int i = off; i < bound; i++) {
            if (b[i] == '\n') {
                buffer.write(b, off, i - off);
                addText();
                off = i + 1;
            }
        }
        assert(off <= bound);
        buffer.write(b, off, bound - off);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        write(b, 0, b.length);
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        // outputs all currently buffered data as a new cell, without receiving
        // a newline as otherwise is required for that
        addText();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        flush();
        buffer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will look into adding a buffer function into my `console` class.

Comment: Your code has been quite useful. Just a problem: I'm getting my console output split on different lines even without a newline character. I'm trying to modify the write method using both offset and length, but with no avail. Any hint on how to fix this behaviour? Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean for the condition to be `b[i]=='\n'`? There isn't much sense in comparing the index to the newline constant... is there?

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. Thank you for replying both here and to my new question.