# JavaFX - Redirecting console output to a ListView splits my System.out.println() output

Tags: java, listview, javafx, console, outputstream

Having managed to output my console to a TextArea in JavaFX, I've tried to achieve the next step: using a nice ListView. I've nailed it and it works better than a simple TextArea (less resource consuming), but I'm having a strange issue.

First of all, I've taken as an example the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589410/replicating-console-functionality-with-a-listview/48589707#48589707).
The proposed code in the accepted answer works pretty good, but in my case it presents a strange behaviour: my output gets split after 9 characters and, sometimes, a character is missing.

[image: Console ListView]

This is the method I'm using to setup my console:

```
private void setUpConsole() {
    Console console = new Console(textAreaLog);
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(console, true);
    System.setOut(ps);
}
```

This, for completeness, is the Task I'm binding to a thread used to manage the console redirection, lifting the JavaFX GUI from its heavy load:

```
private void consoleTask() {
    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            setUpConsole();

            return null;
        }
    };

    Thread th = new Thread(task);
    th.setDaemon(true);
    th.start();
}
```

This is my Console class, which I left pretty the same than the one proposed in the aforementioned link.

```
public class Console extends OutputStream {

private javafx.scene.control.ListView<String> output;
    private ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


    Console(javafx.scene.control.ListView<String> output)  {
        this.output = output;
    }

    private void addText() throws IOException {
        String text = buffer.toString("UTF-8");
        buffer.reset();

        Platform.runLater(() -> output.getItems().add(text));
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        if (b == '\n') {
            addText();
        } else {
            buffer.write(b);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        int bound = off + len;

        for (int i = off; i < bound; i++) {
            if (i == '\n') {
                buffer.write(b, off, i - off);
                addText();
                off = i + 1;
            }
        }

        assert(off <= bound);
        buffer.write(b, off, bound - off);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        write(b, 0, b.length);
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        // outputs all currently buffered data as a new cell, without receiving
        // a newline as otherwise is required for that
        addText();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        flush();
        buffer.close();
    }

}
```

Any hints about how to fix my Console class to get rid of that nasty behaviour?

Comment: From a quick glance - why is the condition `i=='\n'`? Should probably be `b[i]=='\n'`...

Comment: Yep, thank you very much: that was the main issue of my code.
Now I've to understand why I'm getting so many blank lines (3) between each new group. Can be caused by the way I'm parsing the `\n` character?

Comment: Consider what the logic is supposed to do - it's supposed to split into items whenever a newline character is encountered... So it should check if the **character** is a new line... instead, it checks whether the index of the character equals the numerical value of a newline character... which is nonsensical.

Comment: Yes, that was the great flaw that got over my eyes. About the blank lines in excess I think I should play around with `System.out.print()` instead of `System.out.println()`. Doing that partially fixes the issue, even if adding `\n` at the end of the string printed out with `System.out.print()` adds two white lines instead of only one.